# git push not updating the cloned from repo

Tags: git

I did the following

1. git clone from another repo say Release1
2. made changes to cloned repo
3. committed changes
4. pushed changes to both master and Release1
5. pulled changes from cloned folder in Release1
6. status/log is showing my changes at both places
7. The update is not reflected at Release1

What did I miss in the above steps? Both repo are in same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do a

> git --hard HEAD

to the parent repo  from where I have cloned

Answer (score 2):

I think that's

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Chhets!